# Cannot deserialize blob field from cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, blob, cql

My cassandra table definition is as below:

```
    Create table userInfo(
        mandatory_info1 int PRIMARY KEY;
        mandatory_info2 float;
        mandatory_info3 int;
        additional_info1 int;
        additional_info2 String;
        additional_info3 double;
    );
```

Here 3 additional_info field will be used for some specific users.

I want to use a single field of blob type to store this additional info.(As name of these fields seems weird for normal users). So, my table definition becomes as below:

```
    Create table userInfo(
        mandatory_info1 int PRIMARY KEY;
        mandatory_info2 float;
        mandatory_info3 int;
        additional_info blob;
    );
```

I created following java class which will hold the additional infos:

```
    class Additional_Info{
        private int additional_info1;
        private String additional_info2;
        private double additional_info3;

        //setter and getter method goes here
    }
```

Then I can put user's additional info in the blob field by serializing object of type Additional_Info. And by
deserializing this blob field additional info can be retrived.

However, If I add another addition_info(say: additional_info4) in my class. My class become incompatible with
the previously inserted blob values. As a result I couldn't retrive previous records (java.io.InvalidClassException occurs). This also happens if
member varibles name of this class changed.

Is there any other optimal way to store the addition fields in cassandra DB(instead of using different column for each
additional field). If not how can I overcome above mentioned problem.